# Upload Unity presentation remotely on Android

Tags: android, rest

You can upload presentations (animations) made in 3D remotely Unity, coming from a server ?

My knowledge in Unity is low and, while trying to export the Unity project to Android Studio is apparently the '.so' format.

Even so you can load via server ? If so how could it be done ?

Comment: for general questions, try GameDev.com.  this site is only for specific problems in source code.  what you're looking for is the "assetBundles" system in Unity - they have a huge amount of doco on it, enjoy